# Update and delete in same Api view without passing id in Url

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

How to perform crud operation in One URL End point in django rest framework?

Currently i am having 2 url end points

```
url(r'^recipient/$', views.RecipientView.as_view()), # in this APiview im performing get all and post
url(r'^recipient/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.RecipientDetail.as_view()), # in this APiview im performing retrieve, update delete.
```

Now the requirement is i have remove 2nd url and perform all operations in first api view?

I am new to django framework can anyone please help me achieve this?

Below is my code.

View.py

```
class RecipientView(APIView):

     def get(self, request, format=None):
         Recipients = Recipient.objects.all()
         serializer = RecipientSerializer(Recipients, many=True)
         return Response(serializer.data)

     def post(self, request, format=None):
         serializer = RecipientSerializer(data=request.data)
         if serializer.is_valid():
             serializer.save()
             return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
         return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)


"""
class RecipientDetail(APIView):


    def get_object(self, pk):
        try:
            return Recipient.objects.get(pk=pk)
        except Recipient.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404

    def get(self, request, pk, format=None):
        Recipient = self.get_object(pk)
        serializer = RecipientSerializer(Recipient)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def put(self, request, pk, format=None):
        Recipient = self.get_object(pk)
        serializer = RecipientSerializer(Recipient, data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    def delete(self, request, pk, format=None):
        Recipient = self.get_object(pk)
        Recipient.delete()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
"""
```

model.py

```
class Recipient(models.Model):
    recipient = models.CharField(max_length=32, blank=False, null=False)
    def __str__(self):
        """returns the model as string."""
        return self.racipi
```

ent

serializer.py

```
class RecipientSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Recipient
        fields = '__all__'
```

I am not able to update and delete in the same view please needed help?

Comment: How would you specify what object to update /delete?  The second endpoint is made exactly for this -  to provide object pk.

Comment: Why do you want to remove the second route?

Comment: Hi guys the above code is working perfectly for all crud operations. Please advice which is the best to way choose api end points in DRF.            My senior suggested me using 2 url endpoints is not a best practice.         So i need to do all the operations in one url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can avoid passing the ID in the URL with a POST request. Supply the ID and some kind of "action" verb, e.g. `action=delete` in the body of the request.

That's not considered RESTful though, partly because the HTTP DELETE and PUT verbs perfectly describes the requested operations, but also because POST is considered a non-idempotent method, meaning that the server state will change with each successful request. Being idempotent, duplicate DELETE/PUT (and GET for that matter) requests will leave the server in the same state.

It's not a major hassle to have a second route and view to implement the REST API so it's best to leave it as it is.

Answer (score 0):

Your 2nd URL is receiving a parameters that can be used to fetch data object from the database and then perform any action on that particular instance. If you see the class `RecipientDetail`, you'll see all the methods are accepting a parameter called `pk` that relates to the object you want to fetch from database.

But your 1st URL is for generic actions like `Create New Object` or `List All Objects` and it is not good to use these endpoints to do instance specific actions.

You can read more about REST API standard enpoints to know details. Here is a reference link:

https://www.vinaysahni.com/best-practices-for-a-pragmatic-restful-api

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use DRF's [ViewSet](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/).  It already provides the basic CRUD operation for you so you can just create the view in something like this:

```
# views.py
from rest_framework import viewsets

from .models import Recipient
from .serializers import RecipientSerializer


class RecipientViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    A viewset for viewing and editing recipient instances.
    """
    serializer_class = RecipientSerializer
    queryset = Recipient.objects.all()
```

Since we are using ModelViewSet, it already provides actions like get, list, update, etc. as you can see in the [documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#modelviewset).

You can then use [routers](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/) in your urls.py like this:

```
# urls.py
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter

from myapp.views import RecipientViewSet

router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'recipients', RecipientViewSet)
urlpatterns = router.urls
```

The url above will generate a url that is like what you wrote in you question:

```
# Add recipient
POST /recipients/

# Get list of recipients
GET /recipients/

# Get recipient detail
GET /recipients/:recipient_id/

# Update recipient
PUT/PATCH /recipients/:recipient_id/

# Delete recipient
DELETE /recipients/:recipient_id/
```

Please take note that this is a simplified version and you can even create your own urls pattern with your specified actions.

**UPDATE:**

Thanks to mhawke for clarification.  As what mhawke said in the comment, this may not be what the OP wanted, if you just want to avoid passing the ID in the url, then you can follow mawke's answer, and yes it is not considered RESTful.

Comment: This is nice, but it still requires multiple routes which I think the OP is trying to avoid for some unspecified reason.

Comment: Ahh yeah, it seems I misunderstood the question, I just thought he wanted to have only one view for both actions.

Comment: Having one view that handles CRUD is an improvement, especially as there's so little code. It's also good that the routes are generated from a single definition. Perhaps the OP will explain their motivation.